# Trying to understand prefix sum execution

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to understand the scan implementation scan-then-fan mentioned in the book: The CUDA Handbook.

1. Can some one explain the device function `scanWarp`? Why negative indexes? Could you please mention a numerical example?
2. I have the same question about for the line `warpPartials[16+warpid] = sum`. How the assignment is happening?
3. Which is the contribution of this line `if ( warpid==0 ) {scanWarp<T,bZeroPadded>( 16+warpPartials+tid ); }`
4. Could you please someone explain `sum += warpPartials[16+warpid-1];` ? An numerical example will be highly appreciated.
5. Finally, a more c++ oriented question how do we know the indexes that are used in `*sPartials = sum;` to store values in `sPartials`?

**PS:** A numerical example that demonstrates the whole execution would be very helpful.

```
template < class T, bool bZeroPadded > 
inline __device__ T
scanBlock( volatile T *sPartials ){


   extern __shared__ T warpPartials[];
   const int tid = threadIdx.x;
   const int lane = tid & 31;
   const int warpid = tid >> 5;

   //
   // Compute this thread's partial sum
   //
   T sum = scanWarp<T,bZeroPadded>( sPartials );
   __syncthreads();

   //
   // Write each warp's reduction to shared memory
   // 
   if ( lane == 31 ) {
       warpPartials[16+warpid] = sum;
   }
   __syncthreads();

   //
   // Have one warp scan reductions
   //
   if ( warpid==0 ) {
       scanWarp<T,bZeroPadded>( 16+warpPartials+tid );
   }
   __syncthreads();

   //
   // Fan out the exclusive scan element (obtained
   // by the conditional and the decrement by 1)
   // to this warp's pending output
   //
   if ( warpid > 0 ) {
       sum += warpPartials[16+warpid-1];
   }
   __syncthreads();

   //
   // Write this thread's scan output
   //
   *sPartials = sum;
   __syncthreads();

   //
   // The return value will only be used by caller if it
   // contains the spine value (i.e. the reduction
   // of the array we just scanned).
   //
   return sum;
}


template < class T >
inline __device__ T 
scanWarp( volatile T *sPartials ){

   const int tid = threadIdx.x;
   const int lane = tid & 31;

   if ( lane >=  1 ) sPartials[0] += sPartials[- 1];
   if ( lane >=  2 ) sPartials[0] += sPartials[- 2];
   if ( lane >=  4 ) sPartials[0] += sPartials[- 4];
   if ( lane >=  8 ) sPartials[0] += sPartials[- 8];
   if ( lane >= 16 ) sPartials[0] += sPartials[-16];

   return sPartials[0];
}
```

Comment: There was nothing in the book that explains it?

Comment: In the book there are basic explanations like for example the specific part of the code refers to the specific step of the algorithm not details that could help me to answer my questions. In other words, there is not a step by step explanation of each function except from the comments.

Comment: Is there a full code provided in the book? It's not clear to me how `scanBlock` is called. I assume that is called in a similar way as `scanWarp<T,bZeroPadded>( 16+warpPartials+tid )` - as parameter a base index + threadIdx.x as offset.

Comment: Yes there is https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/tree/master/scan/int

Comment: I would like to thanks both users for their answers but I need some time to understand their posts and read the recommended documents which I found very interesting. After doing that I will come back because I already have multiple questions especially for the @ArchaeaSoftware answer. I other words I need some time to understand a few thing better before start commenting. Thanks you!. __PS:__Please remember I am actually a beginner, few months working seriously c++ and Cuda:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer rewritten now I have more time)

Here's an example (based on an implementation I wrote in C++ AMP, not CUDA). To make the diagram smaller each warp is 4 elements wide and a block is 16 elements.

[image]

The following paper is also pretty useful [Efficient Parallel Scan Algorithms for GPUs](https://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/publications/nvr-2008-003.pdf). As is [Parallel Scan for Stream Architectures](https://sites.google.com/site/duanemerrill/ScanTR2.pdf).

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. They are using the middle of the array and offsetting from it.

Comment: Duane Merrill's paper (https://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/publications/nvr-2008-003.pdf) contains an overview of several Scan strategies (including the fan-then-scan described by Sungupta et al.), then presents the reduce-then-scan strategy that is more efficient and only requires O(1) intermediate space.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware that's the paper I referenced in my answer.

Comment: @Ade, the paper that you referenced appears to be Sengupta et al., which only describes one of the 3 scan strategies discussed by Merrill (and The CUDA Handbook).

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware then I think your link is incorrect, both links load nvr-2008-003.pdf.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware added a link to the paper I thin you are referring to. Let me know if it's not the right one.

Comment: You are right, the link I provided was incorrect and you dug up the paper I was talking about.

Answer (score 3):

The scan-then-fan strategy is applied at two levels.  For the grid-level scan (which operates on global memory), partials are written to the temporary global memory buffer allocated in the host code, scanned by recursively calling the host function, then added to the eventual output with a separate kernel invocation.  For the block-level scan (which operates on shared memory), partials are written to the base of shared memory (`warpPartials[]`), scanned by one warp, then added to the eventual output of the block-level scan.  The code that you are asking about is doing the block-level scan.

1. The implementation of `scanWarp` that you are referencing is called with a shared memory pointer that has already had `threadIdx.x` added to it, so each thread's version of `sPartials` points to a different shared memory element.  Using a fixed index on `sPartials` causes adjacent threads to operate on adjacent shared memory elements.  Negative indices are okay as long as they do not result in out-of-bounds array indexing.  This implementation borrowed from the optimized version that pads shared memory with zeros, so every thread can unconditionally use a fixed negative index and threads below a certain index just read zeros. (Listing 13.14)  It could just as easily have predicated execution on the lowest threads in the warp and used positive indices.
2. The 31st thread of each 32-thread warp contains that warp's partial sum, which has to be stored somewhere in order to be scanned and then added to the output. `warpPartials[]` aliases shared memory from the first element, so can be used to hold each warp's partial sum.  You could use any part of shared memory to do this calculation, because each thread already has its own scan value in registers (the assignment `T sum = scanWarp...`).
3. Some warp (it could be any warp, so it might as well be warp 0) has to scan the partials that were written to `warpPartials[]`. At most one warp is needed because there is a hardware limitation of 1024 threads per block = 1024/32 or 32 warps.  So this code is taking advantage of the coincidence that the maximum number of threads per block, divided by the warp count, is no larger than the maximum number of threads per warp.
4. This code is adding the scanned per-warp partials to each output element.  The first warp already has the correct values, so the addition is done only by the second and subsequent warps.  Another way to look at this is that it's adding the exclusive scan of the warp partials to the output.
5. `scanBlock` is a device function - the address arithmetic gets done by its caller, `scanAndWritePartials`: `volatile T *myShared = sPartials+tid;`