# How scan warp is executed

Tags: matlab, cuda

I am trying to understand the execution of the following code

```
template < class OP , ScanKind Kind , class T >
__device__ T scan_warp ( volatile T * ptr , const unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x )
{
     const unsigned int lane = idx & 31; // index of thread in warp (0..31)
/*1*/if ( lane >= 1) ptr [ idx ] = OP :: apply ( ptr [ idx - 1] , ptr [ idx ]);
/*2*/if ( lane >= 2) ptr [ idx ] = OP :: apply ( ptr [ idx - 2] , ptr [ idx ]);
/*3*/if ( lane >= 4) ptr [ idx ] = OP :: apply ( ptr [ idx - 4] , ptr [ idx ]);
/*4*/if ( lane >= 8) ptr [ idx ] = OP :: apply ( ptr [ idx - 8] , ptr [ idx ]);
/*5*/if ( lane >= 16) ptr [ idx ] = OP :: apply ( ptr [ idx - 16] , ptr [ idx ]);
/*6*/if( Kind == inclusive ) return ptr [ idx ];
     else return ( lane >0) ? ptr [ idx -1] : OP :: identity ();
}
```

by writing an example.

**Example:**

*input*: `[ 3 4 5 2 1 7 8 9 ]` 
*correct output:* `[ 3 7 12 14 15 22 30 39 ]`

- **step1:**  `threadIdx.x = 0`, `lane = 0`, *output*: `[ 3 4 5 2 1 7 8 9 ]`, (no `if` statement execution)
- **step2:**  `threadIdx.x = 1`, `lane = 1`, *output*: `[ 3 7 5 2 1 7 8 9 ]`,(/* 1*/ executed)
- **step3:**  `threadIdx.x = 2`, `lane = 2`, *outputTemp*: `[ 3 7 12 2 1 7 8 9 ]`,((/* 1*/ executed)) ,*outputFinal*: `[ 3 7 15 2 1 7 8 9 ]`,(/* 2 */ executed)

In **step3** the `outputTemp` is obtained from the `output` in **step2** by applying the first `if` statement. The `outputFinal` is obtained by applying the second `if` statement in `outputTemp`. So in the third element of the final output there is an error. Instead of 12 we have 15.

**Questions:**

1. What is wrong with my skeptic in thread excecution? Could you please describe the thread execution?
2. Why do we use `const unsigned int lane = idx & 31;` to check the conditions in `if` statements and not the `idx` it self. I mean that if `idx = [0 1...31]` `lane` is also `[0 1 2...31]`.
3. Is there any possible way to visualize the thread execution in matlab?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You did notice the tests in that function are `lane >=` not `lane ==`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have noticed it and for that reason depending on the `lane` value the corresponding `if` statement executed. Am I still missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to understand prefix sum execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210120/trying-to-understand-prefix-sum-execution)

Comment: This question is not concentrated in the specific part of the code but in the general execution. Moreover, the corresponding functions are not exactly the same in their appearance at least. Because I had difficulties in the previous post I start from something more simple like the function in this post. I hope I did not cause any trouble:) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The code you have shown is a *warp* scan operation, meaning that is it executed simultaneously by all 32 threads within a given warp. Assuming that `OP::apply` is an addition operation, this implies the following sequence of intermediate values

   Input  [ 3 4 5 2 1 7 8 9 ]

   Step 1 [ 3 7 9 7 3 8 15 17]        lanes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 execute `OP::apply( ptr[idx-1], ptr[idx])`

   Step 2 [ 3 7 12 14 12 15 18 25 ]   lanes 2,3,4,5,6,7 execute `OP::apply( ptr[idx-2], ptr[idx])`

   Step 3 [ 3 7 12 14 15 22 30 39 ]   lanes 4,5,6,7 execute `OP::apply( ptr[idx-4], ptr[idx])`

   Note also that this code expects there to be exactly 32 input values, so trying to run it on the example you supplied would produce a runtime error.
2. Because a typical block contains more than 32 threads (i.e. more then 1 warp), and the idea that the code can be used for any warp in a block. So the same calculation for `threadIdx.x = 0..31` can also be used for `threadIdx.x = 128..159` or `threadIdx.x = 992..1023`
3. Probably, but a pen and paper is a far better tool.

Comment: Thanks @talomnies for the clarification you help was priceless.